# Accessing overridden methods from a mixin in Scala

Tags: scala, traits

I think I've read somewhere that this is possible.

#### Use case

I want to create a trait that when mixed in memoizes the hashCode by overwriting the method and storing the result of the overwritten method in a val.

```
trait MemoHashCode {
  val hashCode = callToOverwritten_hashCode
}
```

Comment: You mean “overridden,” not “overwritten.” Try the `super` keyword.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use the `super` keyword:

```
trait MemoHashCode { 
  val hashCode = super.hashCode
}
```

That is possible because every trait implicitly extends `AnyRef` which has `hashCode` defined. 
If you want to use methods not defined on every object you would have to make sure that the trait can only be mixed in with objects that have the method implemented which you are going to use. That is possible via a self type annotation:

```
trait MemoSomethingElse { 
  this: SomeType => // SomeType has method somethingElse
  val somethingElse = super.somethingElse
}
```

Comment: Somehow I thought it must be more complicated because the trait doesn't know where it will get mixed in. But your explanation made it clear why it works.

Comment: Be careful with structural typing (i.e., identifying a type through members that it defined instead of through a “normal” type name), like in the `this: { def somethingElse: Int } =>` line. Calls to such methods are implemented with Java reflexion and hit the performance.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.
    scala> trait MemoSomethingElse {
      |   this: { def somethingElse: Int } =>
      |   val somethingElse = super.somethingElse
      | }
    <console>:7: error: value somethingElse is not a member of java.lang.Object with ScalaObject
    val somethingElse = super.somethingElse